# Render markdown text from <pre> tags with marked.min.js

Tags: javascript, markdown, javascript-marked

I'm currently working on a online text editing system that works with markdown files. The editor works fine (markdown input is parsed with marked.min.js for the preview while the user edits the file), but I found a weird hiccup when implementing a page for display-only purposes.

I want to use the same markdown parser, so the file has to be parsed at the side of the client with marked.min.js
I wanted to pass the markdown code within `<pre>`-tags, such that if the js fails for some reason, the markdown file is displayed as it would be in a normal text-editor (the best readable format). To parse and replace the text with the formatted text I just use the following:

```
window.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById('markdown-description').innerHTML =
            marked(document.getElementById('markdown-raw').innerHTML);
}
```

However I see that somehow all quotes are not parsed all, while it does work in the editor. I can see all `>` marks when I disable the parser and view the markdown file inbetween the `<pre>` tags.
Even the following works:

```
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('markdown-description').innerHTML =
 marked('# This\n\This is a HTML5 Markdown editor.\n\n> The overriding design goal for Markdown\'s\n> formatting syntax is to make it as readable\n> as possible.\n\nThis text you see here ');
    }
```

Can someone explain why this is going wrong?

My HTML code:

```
<div class="description" id="markdown-description"><pre id="markdown-raw"> # Dillinger

Dillinger is a cloud-enabled, mobile-ready, offline-storage, AngularJS powered HTML5 Markdown editor.



  - Type some Markdown on the left
  - See HTML in the right
  - Magic

Markdown is a lightweight markup language based on the formatting conventions that people naturally use in email.  As [John Gruber] writes on the [Markdown site][df1]

> The overriding design goal for Markdown's
> formatting syntax is to make it as readable
> as possible. The idea is that a
> Markdown-formatted document should be
> publishable as-is, as plain text, without
> looking like it's been marked up with tags
> or formatting instructions.

This text you see here  </pre></div>
```

Comment: What's `markdown-description` and what's `markdown-raw`. Kindly share your HTML please.

Comment: I have added the relevant part of the HTML

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No, there are no errors. All markdown is parsed correctly except for the quotes, those are displayed as a normal paragraphs with the `>` still in the text.

Comment: Adding a space before the `>` works?

Comment: No, adding spaces doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, but did that work? Okay, can you make a http://jsbin.com for this?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hoyilomace/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks. Lemme check.

Comment: Looks like you need to speak to the team of Marked in GitHub and it really looks like an issue from their side. Checked with showdown and it worked well.